# Reading data stream into managed object context?

Tags: ios, core-data, base64

I have seen a slick method for upgrading user data from one iOS app to another across the sandboxes; the destination app registers as a special URL handler and the origin app base64-encodes an entire file and sends it as a plaintext string to the specialized URL, which the destination app decodes and saves to filesystem.

Is it possible to encode the origin's managed object context & send that & have the destination parse that *into* it's managed object context?  That is, instead of over-writing the destinations data, merge the incoming data?  Is the answer to this question simply "You can do whatever you want with the incoming data"?

EDIT:

I have not used but am planning on using the data-to-text-to-url-to-url-handler-to-data method discussed [here](http://mobileorchard.com/lite-to-paid-iphone-application-data-migrations-with-custom-url-handlers/).  ASSUMING that this works, my question is I guess, can the destination parse the data as managed objects that I insert into the destination managed object context?  The origin and destination have the same managed object model.

Comment: No, you can't share memory between application instances like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do may be possible if you send the contents of the entire .sqlite file itself. You would have to have your destination app build up an entire (i.e. `NSPersistentObjectStoreCoordinator`) Core Data stack from the file that got saved into the destination sandbox. `NSManagedObjectID`s are preferable if you have two stacks already pointing to the same URL (that you created the `NSManagedObjectModel` with, and subsequently init'ed the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` with by `[[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model]`.

Comment: So I can pull it off if I save the transferred data to a persistent store in the destination, and then pull it into the destination's managed object context, and then save that merged context.  I will try this tout suite!

Comment: Yes, though I'd word it as "save transferred data to a new .sqlite file, then build up a completely new NSPersistentStoreCoordinator pointing to it, *then* create a new NSManagedObjectContext that uses this new NSPersistentStoreCoordinator"  :)

Comment: So far so good; I have two object contexts, both using the same object model, but each using it's own persistent store.  Now I would like to add the data from one context into the other, but the attributes have relationships, which now become relationships across stores when I try to add then object by object.  Do I create a 3rd context with a new model that does not have the relationships but has attributes to hold the set of id's in the relationships?

Comment: I thought your original question was about an upgrade of a .xcdatamodel (and associated models obviously) from a different iOS app/sandbox. If you are trying to keep any data in place, you need to look at Core Migrations, which allows you to release changes to your .xcdatamodel (such as add relationships, columns, etc) while keeping the data in place.

Comment: Thank you @scc, you;ve been a huge help!

Comment: No problem. If you think it answered the question, mark it as correct :)